# Quando o "Programmers" mudou para "Software Engineering"?

Tags: debate

Apenas uma curiosidade:

Eu tenho conta no site https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, mas eu me lembro que antes ele era https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. Hoje por exemplo o segundo link redireciona para o primeiro.

Alguém sabe quando mudou de nome? Sabem porque? Procurei no Google, mas não achei.

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia! Foi recente, dia 20/10: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8054

Comment: Votei por fechar porque é off-topic, o META é uma lugar para discutir problemas e situações site principal ao qual se refere, no caso este META se refere ao pt.stackoverflow.com. A unica exceção geralmente são BUGs que afetam a rede toda.

Comment: Esqueci de procurar nesse meta. Estou ruim de Google esses dias. Pode fechar então. Foi mal

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com um debate no meta deles [*(4 years later) Dear Stack Exchange: can we change our site name?*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7935/4-years-later-dear-stack-exchange-can-we-change-our-site-name/)), isso já era uma vontade antiga, mas a rede havia recusado a mudança 4 anos atrás.

Em março desse ano, foi feito um novo pedido. A discussão caminhou, e [o site foi renomeado em 20 de outubro de 2016](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8054).

Comment: A ideia do Programmers nunca foi muito boa. Mas o SE.SE tem um conteúdo esquisito, ainda que parece que limparam um pouco (ou seja, jogaram fora muita coisa). Eu ainda acho que eles é desnecessário.

Comment: Aproveitando a deixa, pergunto-lhes(ao @bigown e ao bfavaretto): esta pergunta não é fora do escopo, ou posso usar o meta para fazer questionamentos de outros sites da rede?

Comment: @diegofm É um pouquinho sim, talvez seja o caso de fechar, mas não vejo ela como um problema porque em português não poderia ser feito em outro lugar. Se bem que se é sobre SE.SE, a pessoa deveria saber inglês. O dia que eu entrei e vi que mudou, eu fui quente no meta lá ver onde falava da mudança.

Comment: Cara eu sei inglês e estudei um ano em universidade americana. Perguntei aqui por falha minha. Devia ter pesquisado mais. Me desculpe.

Comment: Tudo bem @Murilo, mas tem gente aqui neste site que não fala inglês, então esta pergunta seria o único lugar onde achariam a resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas é uma dúvida totalmente externa so sopt, não? Por que eu já tive dúvidas semelhantes sobre sites da rede  não perguntei aqui no meta por achar que não fazia parte do escopo.

Comment: @diegofm Eu também achei off-topic quando vi, mas depois considerei que  podia ser útil mesmo assim. Agora, já respondida, tanto faz por mim se ficar aberta ou fechada.